# Get-stat equivalent via VMWare vSphere API

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I'm developing an application that requires frequent access to the information that is provided through the [PowerCLI Get-Stat](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/Get-Stat.html) command, and continuously interfacing with PowerShell has proven to be too slow.

We've been looking through the VMWare vSphere, but have had little success when it comes to finding a method that provides equivalent information. We have managed to access a [VirtualMachine object](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc%2Fvim.VirtualMachine.html), but it does not appear to provide any clear access to the Stats.

Is there a proper way to access the stats from the API? Or should I focus on optimising PowerShell interaction instead, parsing the resulting output?

Answer (score 0):

If not using VMWare get-stat. You can use:

- Direct VSphere access to DB performance stats.

try something like:

```
SELECT [SAMPLE_TIME]
  ,[SAMPLE_INTERVAL]
  ,[STAT_ID]
  ,[STAT_NAME]
  ,[STAT_GROUP]
  ,[STAT_ROLLUP_TYPE]
  ,[COUNTER_ID]
  ,[ENTITY]
  ,[DEVICE_NAME]
  ,[DEVICE_TYPE_NAME]
  ,[STAT_VALUE]
FROM [VSP02].[dbo].[VPXV_HIST_STAT_DAILY]
```

Take a look at this to use powershell to make SQL querys: https://sorrycantdothat.wordpress.com/category/sysadmin/

- Connect to each VM's WMI and collect performance stats.